# Lef $f \colon \mathbb{R}→ \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.Which of the following is always true?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}→ \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.Which of the following is always true?
>   1. $f ^{-1}(U)$ is open for all open sets $U ⊆\mathbb{R}$
>   2. $f ^{-1}(C)$ is closed for all closed sets $C ⊆\mathbb{R}$
>   3. $f ^{-1}(K)$ is compact for all compact sets $K⊆ \mathbb{R}$
>   4. $f ^{-1}(G)$ is connected for all connected sets $G ⊆ \mathbb{R}$

1 and 2 are always true but i am not sure about the others.can somebody help me

Comment: Have you tried looking at different examples of continuous functions to see if 3 and 4 are true for those examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(3) is not true. Consider the function $f(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. $\{0\}$ is compact but $f^{-1}(0)=\mathbb R$ is not.

(4) is not true. Consider the function $f(x)=(x-2)(x+2)$ for $x\in\mathbb R$. $\{0\}$ is connected but $f^{-1}(0)=\{-2,2\}$ is not.

Comment: I would have used the sine function for my counterexample for 3 and 4.

Answer (score 7):

(3) What if $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$?

(4) What if $f(x)=x^2$ and $G=\{1\}$?